# AzCopy - Bypassing file permissions

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, azure, file-permissions

So, I have in the past granted my account on a server with **SeBackupPrivileges** which has allowed me to run things like Robocopy with the /ZB flag to bypass permissons.

However, I now want to run AzCopy to copy files to blob storage. I have SeBackupPrivileges and I run it in an Administrator command prompt but still get an unauthorised exception:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException
```

How can I start the command prompt in such a way that SeBackupPrivileges are automatically granted to the programs being run?

**UPDATE**

After some searching on the web it looks like in order to take advantage of SeBackupPrivileges one must be using the Windows backup interface which I am not sure AzCopy uses ( guessing not! )
[image]

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc976700.aspx

Comment: Maybe try the trick of using Sysinternals PSEXEC to run another shell as the system account, and then run AZCOPY from within that shell? `psexec -s cmd`

Comment: @Clayton Just tried this, it doesn't work because it needs to be working with the Windows Backup API